# AngularJS rowspan for repeated data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rows

I have an Array which has Role and Screen variables.

Role variable can be repeated in this array.

I want to create rowspan for repeated data.

How can I do this easily?

My pseudocode is in below

**Angular**

```
$scope.testData=[
    {"Role":"Admin","Screen":"A"},
    {"Role":"Admin","Screen":"B"},
    {"Role":"Admin","Screen":"C"},
    {"Role":"Standard","Screen":"H"},
    {"Role":"Standard","Screen":"FH"},
];
```

**HTML**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="detail in Roles">
        <td>{{detail.Role}}</td>
        <td>{{detail.Screen}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I need the  output in below

```
<table>
   <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Admin</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Standard</td>
        <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>EEE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how do you need the output?

Comment: can you post the hardcoded html of how you want the table output to look (i.e. without angular)?

Comment: Thanks for answers guys. @SlavaUtesinov your answer is partially correct but my data structure like testData and I want to create my output using my Array with AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your object to look like (Using angular.forEach() for example)

```
$scope.testData = [
    {"Role":"Admin","Screen":["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"Role":"Standard","Screen": ["H", "FH"]}
];
```

Then it's too easy for your rowspan table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, val) in testData">
        <td rowspan="{{val.Screen.length}}">{{val.Role}}</td>
        <td>{{val.Screen[0]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="value in val.Screen.slice(1)">
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool.. Thank you so much